# ASP.NET MVC3 HTML Modification View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am first time trying on ASP.NET MVC3 , defined the model (C#) and generated the controllers and views
  Views is using HTML Helpers . How to change the textbox , textarea length ( ie HTML attributes) .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify htmlAtrributes (object) parameter in in the following manner to specify html attributes for the text box.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, new { @class = "someclass", width= "yourvalue" })
```

Comment: Where i can found the documentation regd. this?